# Database replication on numerous raspberry pi

Tags: python, linux, database, raspberry-pi, database-replication

I'm currently working on a project with numerous RBPi let's say over 50 divided in network of 10 at most, each of this Raspberry pi get data from humans or sensors, the data rate is about 100Hz at most. My goal is to reduce the loss of data if one of the Raspberry pi was to fail so I want to introduce database replication between the raspberry pi in the same network.

I had a look to cluster like Cassandra on Pi as described by http://fr.slideshare.net/acobley
and My Sql cluster http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/mysql-cluster-running-on-raspberry-pi

but I can't identify if it would work, the point is in this clusters there is one client and one master, what if the master fail can the client still run query (will an other node become the master)? In my case each of the Pi are clients since they need to run query, can we still identify it to a cluster ?

Thank you for your questions/answers/advices

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra can be run without a single point of failure and will scale performance with number of nodes - so that should work in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Consider a Redis cluster as an alternative. Take a look, for example, to https://nexwebsites.com/iot/iot-cloud-redis.html